# MS Access DB on SharePoint: Multiple users, but different data?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an ADb stored on a SharePoint. This ADb is a backend.

My users don't access the ADb by opening, however I have an Excel Macro file that serves as data collector and from there users submit their records and data to the SharePoint ADb (with the help of ADODB - microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0)

My problem: some users, when submitting data through the Excel file, only they can see what they have submitted on the ADb, but I can't. It seems that the data in the ADb doesn't refresh. And when these users open the ADb from their end, they can see what they have submitted..

Yes, the ADb is Shared, No Locks, and is split..

I am stuck, so any help will be very much appreciated!

If more info needed, pls let me know.

Cheers,
Amine

Comment: Does the data eventually make it to the ADb? Do the users that post the data and can see it also see changes other users (who can't see the first group's changes) make?

Comment: - Does the data eventually make it to the ADb?: yes it does, I have been online with the other users and have seen them submitting data, this has been reflected straight away on the ADb
- Do the users that post the data and can see it also see changes other users (who can't see the first group's changes) make?: no, the data seems to stay with the one user (owner and submitter of the data). This is what I could observe with one user, so I cant tell this goes for all users..

Comment: It looks like a sync timing/lag issue. Unfortunately I don't know enough about SharePoint to say more than that.

Comment: Thanks SunKnight0, I will wait for others, hopefully somebody can help..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. Actually it was my bad, the connection was kept open and wasn't closed at userform close event;

cn.close
set cn = nothing

Rgds,
Amine